# how to solve postfix Debian SMTP marked as spam?

Tags: debian, postfix-mta

I followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-debian-9

everything is ok but the emails are marked as spam.

Delivered-To: ayoubrahmanii@gmail.com Received: by 2002:a1c:6583:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id z125csp3832756wmb; Sun, 19 May 2019 23:02:58 -0700 (PDT) X-Google-Smtp-Source: APXvYqziueJj/ZJLPS+13KERoMfV0zEt47W/eBpcd+Htqf2u1zStAaDcz+c6U752jKxdVu1FUk2y X-Received: by 2002:adf:f909:: with SMTP id b9mr331575wrr.119.1558332178243; Sun, 19 May 2019 23:02:58 -0700 (PDT) ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1558332178; cv=none; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816; b=LOrMD4wo+CSLXptyDCQgukVAqycounfdRRE3HRKhK8eXaSuLFpy7q+d1/WVTptCWSP xc4+JSWrsvd/2mD2hUJxrXsscy7i1RXVh+RcE05ImgTANvxRB0I1BfQXzjuWg8SLhKcy qzztiCZeNEKTy9qtfHCmAmC9J9tMxMyj30JKxepmm5nV6E0DPklBJxHXb81i+8XLRin+ hQnygAHdYLLau1/jI7E+PAYsXVVaBGMVhz0+7QFgXRuAtjs8kd2sNix31PO79AXjMcv5 35JNtFI6OzMEsPSKTlP95CbCJfexgCQBIUhDQbNdfs2gCyATkT1kmOC5kOD3gBdYk2jR vz6Q== ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816; h=from:date:message-id:to:subject:delivered-to; bh=+ipNMrPniPP8KeVBOrZBZ6ytKnOurD1TrvS3ffjvDlo=; b=no4it3vkKAIQ+b/bQdmzyANX8qmpyipEsw/NLd4Yab3f2JNMhNITJERyFMLxByEPNH MfBLKARWiVi4m6dbjZuhH/FFs0QHTRF4ySX3aOB75QqZJY+WU8QJbK8Vf2fdFO1F1SaX wy81FYnuNXCJSn6+9K3zhG78tprVJXUOw0foM0/r58QKU5YPGP0HTt/wM2TqW4VDbus1 RF8j6Nl4ztDpzhjNhmdOxQeqGoLl7qMV6w5RIJTQcIs3m0Gnw01DCnAoftcTwMQF2zIs SFmXaQGtWqeeoCuKBMr4JZMPOd/ft1RFDwBfVDHpYvJi0fxcx+HWgC4cPKBNXxDiYO4o 9X6w== ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 138.68.87.27 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of root@ayoub.localdomain) smtp.mailfrom=root@ayoub.localdomain Return-Path: Received: from ayoub.localdomain ([138.68.87.27]) by mx.google.com with ESMTP id t12si13140561wrr.279.2019.05.19.23.02.58 for ; Sun, 19 May 2019 23:02:58 -0700 (PDT) Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 138.68.87.27 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of root@ayoub.localdomain) client-ip=138.68.87.27; Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 138.68.87.27 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of root@ayoub.localdomain) smtp.mailfrom=root@ayoub.localdomain Received: by ayoub.localdomain (Postfix) id 2931A41315; Mon, 20 May 2019 06:02:58 +0000 (UTC) Delivered-To: root@ayoub.localdomain Received: by ayoub.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 0) id 2577D41316; Mon, 20 May 2019 06:02:58 +0000 (UTC) Subject: This is the subject Content-Type: text/html To: X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 3.1.1) Message-Id: <20190520060258.2577D41316@ayoub.localdomain> Date: Mon, 20 May 2019 06:02:58 +0000 (UTC) From: root

Comment: Did you also configure DKIM and SPF records?

Comment: Have you even tried to read that error message? How should gmail check your mails if your mailserver listens on `ayoub.localdomain`?

Comment: how  to change ayoub.localdomain to something else?

Comment: I didnt configure  DKIM and SPF records

Comment: from the tag-description of [postfix-mta]: QUESTIONS ABOUT POSTFIX ADMINISTRATION ARE OFF-TOPIC. Server admin questions may be asked on [sf].